# Есть ли простой способ индексации БД на elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

Решил познакомиться с elasticsearch.

Как индексировать БД sql? Возможно ли такое сделать? Если да то как?
С использованием плагинов, или писать скрипты, или какие вообще инструменты есть?